# Gitlab CI Pipeline fails with Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have been working on implementing Gitlab CI for my project. I have followed the official documentation and able to execute a pipeline to confirm the proper implementation. When I try to add the template script to my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and starts to execute but and fails with `Null pointer exception`. Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file,

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "29"
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "29.0.3"
ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"

before_script:
- apt-get --quiet update --yes
- apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
- wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip 
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
- unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" 
 >/dev/null
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" 
 >/dev/null
- export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
 - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
- chmod +x ./gradlew
- set +o pipefail
- yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
- set -o pipefail

stages:
- build


build:
stage: build
script:
- $(pwd)/gradlew assembleDebug
artifacts:
 paths:
  - app/build/outputs/
```

when I commit my code, and pipeline executes, I ma getting the following error,[image]

I have no idea why this null pointer exception is occurring, I have tried to tweak around with my `.yml` file but no luck. Any help or helping material would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to tell from the output you have given. It would be worth looking through the "raw" version of the job log (which you can download from that page) and looking for errors, or re-run with `--stacktrace` as the error message says.

Comment: @snim2 Thank you for going through my post. The raw file contains the exact same details as you can see in the screenshot, there is no other detail.

Comment: In that case I think it's worth you running the pipeline again with `--stacktrace` on, so that you can get that extra detail that will help you pinpoint where the error has occurred.

Comment: okay will try it. A quick question though, is this the right way to add NDK to .gitlab-ci.yml, like I did. Can you please have a look if it is configured correctly or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's probably worth reading through the official GitLab / Android template: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/project-templates/android